# Simple Pointer Array Equality Explanation Needed

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Just going back to a bit of C++ programming for uni and remembered why I thought this pointer business is so crazy. Could anyone give me a quick explanation as to whats happening here? Is it possible to get the int 20 in the main function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int *b)
{
    b[0] = 10;
    b[1] = 20;
    printf("\n %i \n ", b[1]); // prints 20
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int a;
    test(&a);
    printf("%i \n", a);    //prints 10
    // printf("%i \n", a[1]);    // doesn't compile - why not 20?
    return 0;
}
```

edit: sorry my simple question was such a burden for some users to deal with and thank you to the users who did actually take it seriously and inform me about the undefined behavior. The reason i asked this question was thanks to a code i found that i couldn't work out how to use. i did not just pull this is out of the air. here it is if anyone is interested. look at the glhUnProjectf function and the last argument how am i meant to use it.
http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluProject_and_gluUnProject_code

Comment: It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: You declared `a` to be an integer in `main`, but you're trying to use it like an array of integers.

Comment: I'm not surprised it doesn't compile: `#include >stdio.h>`... are you trying to fool us?

Comment: b[0] is a valid reference. b[1] is not.

Comment: "I thought this pointer business is so crazy." - Quite the opposite, this code is crazy and pointer buiseness is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, I'm sort of surprised it lets you assign a value to b[1].  I would guess that if you took out the part that does not compile, you will get a segfault when you try to assign 20 to b[1], because your program hasn't been allocated that space in memory.  Anyway, int a is not a pointer, it's a variable, so it can't be indexed like an array.

Just to recap, here's a breakdown of the variables and pointers you have:

int a - a is an integer variable in memory, but your program only cares about the value of the integer, not where it actually is in memory.

&a - this returns a pointer to integer a in memory.  Because pointers to arrays are also just pointers to the first element in the array, the program does not complain when you try to index it

int* b - like a, this is a pointer to an integer, not the integer itself.  As mentioned, pointers can be indexed like arrays ([0], [1] and so on) because a pointer to an array is actually a pointer to the first element in the array.  As was mentioned, trying to index past the memory space you've been allocated, whether or not you actually have an array to index, is undefined behavior (most of the time it will give you a segmentation fault, but it also might return the value that happens to be in memory at the location, which could be literally anything, it isn't even guaranteed to be the same data type).

Answer (score 3):

> doesn't compile - why not 20?

It doesn't compile because `a` is neither an array, nor a pointer. What semantics do you expect when subscripting an integer? It just doesn't make sense.

Apart from that: even if you used `(&a)[1]` (which **does** compile), it wouldn't do any good -- there's nothing at the address `&a + 1` because `a` is one single `int`, not an array of two `int`s. So your program would invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a;
test(&a);
```

allocates a memory for `int` variable, leaving it *uninitialized* and passes its address to function `test`:

```
void test(int *b)
{
    b[0] = 10;
    b[1] = 20;
    printf("\n %i \n ",b[1]);    // prints 20
}
```

which at first initializes this variable to `10`, but then tries to access the `int` that follows in the memory (accessing an array out of bounds with `b[1]`), which yields an ***undefined behavior***.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int *b) // A function that takes a pointer to an int as an input
{
    b[0] = 10; // The value pointed to by b now equals 10 (value of a).
    b[1] = 20; // Not valid. memory at b[1] has not been allocated yet.
    printf("\n %i \n ",b[1]);  
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int a; 
    test(&a); // call test giving address of a (pointer to a as input)
    printf("%i \n",a);    //prints 10, this is because the value pointed by b is 10.
    //printf("%i \n",a[1]);    //doesn't compile - a is not a pointer!
    return 0;
}
```